# Simple validation

Tags: c#, validation, console-application

Hey guys looking for a simple validation code for my C# Console Program

Currently have:

```
public Class1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    while ((input != "a") && "b" && "c" && "d"))
    {
        if (input == "a" && "b" && "c" && "d")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }

        if (input != "a" && "b" && "c" && "d")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try again");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: I should clarify the purpose is for the user to enter a, b, c or d if the input isn't any of these the question will re-display

Answer (score 1):

This is a nonsense :

```
while ((input != "a") && "b" && "c" && "d"))
```

It can be written that way :

```
while (aCondition && anotherCondition && yetAnotherCondition && theLastCondition))
```

`(input != "a")` is a condition, there's no problem with that, but `"b"` isn't a condition, it will be considered as `true` since it's not `false` or `null`. I think you would have write : `while ((input != "a") && (input != "b") && (input != "c") && (input != "d")))`

The same way that condition `if (input == "a" && "b" && "c" && "d")` should have be written `if (input == "a" && input == "b" && input == "c" && input == "d")` will provide an algo issue. `input` can't be at the same time equal to `"a"`, equal to `"b"`, equal to `"c"` and equal to `"d"`.

Plus, your code won't compile since it's in a class without being wrapped into a method.

Did you read the errors message when trying to run it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach would be to create an array of chars that are allowed and validate the input against that:

```
char[] allowedChars = new char[] { 'a', 'b'};   

while(true){

    char inputChar = 'z';

    if (allowedChars.Length > 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter {0} or {1}:", string.Join(", ", allowedChars.Take(allowedChars.Length - 1)), allowedChars[allowedChars.Length - 1]));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter {0}", allowedChars[0]));
    }

    var result = char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputChar);

    if (result && allowedChars.Contains(inputChar))
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Try again");
}

Console.WriteLine("Success");
Console.ReadLine();
```

When it's a success it'll automatically break out from the while loop and print the Success message.

Comment: I suggest printing `"Try again"` in case of *invalid input only*, not on the *first run*. If allowed chars are `a` and `b` only I suggest *building* the title (something like `"Enter a or b:"`) from valid chars, not hardcoding `"Enter a, b, c or d:"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Good suggestions :) I've edited the code!

Comment: Technically, the last `else` is redundant: you can simply put `Console.WriteLine("Try again");`. I doubt if there will be a case with only *one* allowed character (what is the reason to ask user to input it) - `if (allowedChars.Length > 1) ...`. In (academic) general case `HashSet<char>` is a better choice than array for `Contains` (however, in this particular case with a *small* array the difference is negligible). Nice +1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You're right about the last else statement, I've put it in for readability but thinking now it's quite obvious and never knew about the HashSet being a better choice... something to read about in the afternoon. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code cannot just be in a class. It needs to be in a function. Generally you'll see that looking like this

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
    while ((input != "a") &&(input != "b") && (input != "c") &&(input != "d"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try again");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following code:

```
// char: we actually input a single character, not string
char input = '\0'; // initialize to make compiler happy

// keep on asking until success
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:"); 

  // ReadKey: We want a single character, not a string
  input = Console.ReadKey();   

  // input is valid if it's in ['a'..'d'] range
  if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'd') {
    Console.WriteLine("Success");

    break;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Try again"); 
}
```

**Edit**: in generalized case (see Adriani6's comment below) the code be a little bit more complex. I guess the underlying problem being a kind of *questionary*, like

```
Compute 2 x 2 = ?
  a. 3
  b. 4
  c. 5
  d. 0  

Enter a, b, c or d:
```

that's why I expect the valid `input` should ever be in some *range* (`'a'..'d'` in the example above) which I preserved.

```
char from = 'a';
char upto = 'd';

// char: we actually input a single character, not string
char input = '\0'; // initialize to make compiler happy

// Building a title is, probably, the only complex thing (Linq)
string title = 
  $"Enter {string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(from, upto - from).Select(c => (char) c))} or {upto}:";

// keep on asking until success
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine(title); 

  // ReadKey: We want a single character, not a string
  input = Console.ReadKey();   

  // Uncomment if we want a quit without choice, say, on Escape 
  //if (input == 27) { // or (input == 'q') if we want to quit on q
  //  input = '\0';
  //
  //  break;
  //}  

  // input is valid if it's in [from..upto] range
  if (input >= from && input <= upto) {
    Console.WriteLine("Success");

    break;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Try again"); 
}
```

Comment: It's not pretty extensible when using ranges, what if the next task will be to add q to exit? Good solution nonetheless.

Comment: @Adriani6 then you could just do another if-case. Alternatively, handle ``|| 'q'`` within the if-clause.

Comment: @Joel Of course you could, no one says you can't. There are easier ways to make a method more extensible that modifying the logical statement.

Comment: @Adriani6 And I've never said you did. Amongst the solutions, this is clearly the most general one (including the update from 1 min ago)

Comment: @Joel I think you've completely misinterpreted my comments... and this isn't the place to discuss it. My comment was a suggestion for Dmitry and he treated it as one (hence his edit I suppose). This also isn't the most general one, there are easier ways to implement such validation/functionality with even less, cleaner looking code when extending the character ranges and some of the answers reflect exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of mistakes in your code, look at mine and try to understand it. It's pretty easy.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:\r\n");
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   while (input != "")
   {
     if (input == "a" || input == "b" || input == "c" || input == "d")
      {
       Console.WriteLine("Success\r\n");
      }
     else
      {
       Console.WriteLine("Fail\r\n");
      }
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
     input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Class1()
{

    private static List<string> allowedChars= new List<string>(){
         "a","b","c","d"
     };
     public void Verify()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
          string input = Console.ReadLine();
          while (!allowedChars.Contains(input))
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Try again");       
              Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
              input = Console.ReadLine();
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a while loop? It seems quite unneccessary. I do not understand your code as to what the right answer would be, but a simple switch statement should serve your purpose better

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (input)
        {
            case "a": Console.WriteLine("Success");
                break;
            case "b":
                Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                break;
            case "c":
                Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                break;
            case "d":
                Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                break;
            default: Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: A switch statement will not serve the purpose.. I think you're missing the whole point in the while loop..

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would break out the validation code input into a separate method as you're potentially going to have to call it multiple times if the input validation fails. The same applies for retrieving the input.

As for the validation itself, a simple check that the input string matches "a" OR "b" OR "c" OR "d" will work. You can set up the method to return the boolean value that the expression evaluates to, as below.

Finally, it's just a case of calling `ValidateInput` until it returns true using a `While` loop and negating the returned value using the logical negation operator `!`. Negating the returned value effectively reverses the result of the `ValidateInput` method. In English this would read as `While ValidateInput is NOT True`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (!ValidateInput(GetInput()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try again");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static string GetInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a, b, c or d:");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool ValidateInput(string input)
    {
        return (input == "a" || input == "b" || input == "c" || input == "d");
    }
}
```